# mySql function for geopoints distance calculations

Tags: mysql, geopoints

i'm trying to create a mysql function in order to calculate the distance between 2 Geopoints in meters.

This is what i have so far (combination of stuff from Google):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`server.asafnevo.co.il` FUNCTION `getDistance`(
    firstLong float(10,6),
    firstLat float(10,6),
    secondLong float(10,6),
    secondLat float(10,6)
) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
RETURN abs((((acos(sin((firstLat*pi()/180)) * 
            sin((secondLat*pi()/180))+cos((firstLat*pi()/180)) * 
            cos((secondLat*pi()/180)) * cos(((firstLong-secondLong)* 
            pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515
        )) * 1.6093 * 1000;
END
```

This problem is that it doesn't always works an i get 0 distance between points with distance..

any idea how to do it right ?

Comment: In the formula, you may want to change all of the values to decimals: `180` becomes `180.0`, etc.

Comment: you can write it as an answer and i will accept it